# Optimizing CSS - how to properly reduce CSS footprint

Tags: html, css

I was under the impression that it was ideal to bundle your CSS files into one file to reduce the number of HTTP requests.  However, by doing this the final CSS file will contain CSS rules which are not used on that page.

With this in mind, what is considered the best practice for a large site:

1. Bundle all the CSS into one main file so the browser can access the cached file on other pages.
2. Split the CSS into multiple files and only load the files needed for that page to reduce the occurrence of loading unused CSS (this also allows commonly used files to be cached).
3. Use a program to bundle the CSS used for that particular page into one file so only one CSS file is loaded and only the CSS needed for that page is loaded.

I would think #3 would be the best option, but wouldn't that require the browser to re-download the bundled CSS file each time it was changed (a CSS file is added/removed from the bundle)?

Any input appreciated.

Comment: How much bigger is your final file?

Comment: minify & combine is the best way to go, whats your site built on?

Comment: @ Mike Robinson - If I combined all the files and minified them it is around 120kb.

Comment: @ Lucky Chingi - VPS, Apache, Centos 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would think number 3 would be the best option, but most of the time it isn't.

The browser will cache the css file and will not need to download it for subsequent requests, this is why I tend to bundle all of my css for the site and minify it. You take a bit of a hit on the first request, but after that the browser just pulls the file back from the cache.

If you split the css in to different files, the browser will need to make a request for the css on each page first request (after which it will be cached).

Also, from a maintainability point of view, I'd rather have my css in one file.

Answer (score 0):

I would bundle into 1 file.Maintaining multiple files is just a headache.

I would also look into ways of optimizing your CSS, try set a class that handles all button styles for example and go with that.

Your CSS file shouldn't be massive enough to even worry about file size if you ar careful in how you build it.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be minifying CSS files into ONE and placing them on **reliable content delivery network.**

Proper optimization is reducing the transfer as much as you can at the same time guaranteeing it's stability - and CSS is critical element to load.

If there're small CSS updates required I'd recommend placing those into inline styles, and **when those are stable** bundling them into main CSS file.